# How fix errors repo

Tags: package-management, launcher, repository, python3

How to solve my problem with the repo tool after I wrote a command on the terminal
sudo apt install repo
And I updated the Ubuntu operating system, and when I ran the repo tool, it did not work

```
~$ repo
A new version of repo (2.32) is available.

New version is available at: /home/eslam12/.repo/repo/repo The launcher is run from: /usr/bin/repo

!!! The launcher is not writable. Please talk to your sysadmin or distro !!! to get an update installed.

2

repo: reusing existing repo client checkout in /home/eslam12

repo has been initialized in /home/eslam12 If this is not the directory in which you want to initialize repo, please run: rm -r /home/eslam12/.repo and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by copying the downloaded repo script to /usr/bin hence replacing the existing one (which I backed up first).  This using sudo privileges.

```
sudo chmod a+w  /usr/bin/repo
cd /usr/bin/
sudo mv repo repo_00
cd -
cp /home/lu/dev/xxx/.repo/repo/repo /usr/bin/repo 
sudo cp /home/lu/dev/wboxmini/.repo/repo/repo /usr/bin/repo
```

I further modified the first line from

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```